# Find maximum distance between elements given constraints on some

Tags: java, c++, algorithm, optimization, max

I have a list of numbered elements 1 to N that fit into positions on a number line starting with 1. I also have constraints for these elements:

- The element 1 is in position 1, and element N must be at a position >= the position of element N-1. (i.e. element 2 could be at position 1, element 3 at position 7, and element 4 at position 8 (but not position 5))
- Some elements must be within a certain distance from each other on the line.
- Some elements must be at least a certain distance from other on the line.

My objective is to return an integer that represents the maximum span between element 1 and element N. If no lineup is possible, return -1, and if the elements can be any distance apart, return -2.

I am given:

- The number of elements
- A withinArray[][] where withinArray[x][y] = the distance elements x and y must be within on the line. Any zero values represent no constraints.
- An atLeastArray[][] where atLeastArray[x][y] = the distance elements x and y must be apart on the line. Any zero values represent no constraints.

An example input would be: 4 elements, withinArray[1][3] = 10, withinArray[2][4] = 20, and atLeastArray[2][3] = 3. (all other array values are zero).

The return value for this input would be 27. (element 1 at position 1, element 2 at position 8, element 3 at position 11, and element 4 at position 28)

So far, I have come up with this:

```
for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
    for (int j = 1; j < atLeastArray.length; j++) 
        if (j == i)
            positions[i] = positions[j] - atLeastArray[i][j];
    for (int j = 1l j < withinArray.length; j++) 
        if (j == i) 
            positions[j] = positions[i] + withinArray[i][j];
}
return positions[n] - positions[1];
```

This gives me the right answer for the example I have given, but I don't feel confident it works in every case, and I'm not sure how to define the cases when it's impossible or if the elements can be any distance apart.

Comment: Sounds like linear programming

Answer (score 0):

Let's think about this in terms of linear programming.  We have variables x_1, ..., x_n and a bunch of constraints of the form x_i <= x_(i+1), x_i - x_j <= w_{ij}, and x_i - x_j >= a_(ij).

Notice what happens when we do Fourier-Motzkin elimination to a variable --- that is, isolating it in every equation in which it appears, forming two sets of inequalities, say x_i <= foo_k for various k and x_i >= bar_l for various l, and then removing all the constraints involving x_i and replacing them with the constraints bar_l <= foo_k for each k and l.

You'll get more constraints of the same form as you had before!  Notice that, if you know that x_i - x_j <= a and x_i - x_j <= b, you can conclude that x_i - x_j <= min(a,b) and forget the two constraints from before.  So you'll never need more than n^2 constraints.

So just eliminate all the variables except x_1 and x_n.  You'll have two constraints at the end, namely that x_n - x_1 >= a and that x_n - x_1 <= b.  Check that a <= b and that b isn't infinity and you should be good.

Uh, and if someone could teach me how to write math on this thing, I'd be grateful :)